# Extending deployed contract in solidity

Tags: solidity

I need to deploy a lot of typical contracts with identical functionality.

Is there a way for extending the already deployed contract in solidity?

I hope to make a single big contract with main functionality and extend it in all next contracts to save a gas

Comment: can you rephrase your question? it's too wild.

Comment: A contract's bytecode cannot be modified. There are different techniques that allow to extend the functionality but it always involve deploying a new contract. For example https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2535.

Comment: @6egix I mean, I need to deploy a lot of identical contracts to use them as wallets with additional functionality. But the deploying cost a lot of gas. I would like to deploy one contract with all the functionality, and then simply inherit it or use its functionality in some way, so that subsequent contracts are lightweight and require less gas to deploy.